# How to go through Azure Blobs without memory problems

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to convert the access tier of our blobs in Azure storage from Cool to Archive.
I am using a Powershell script for this, but once i get to some of our containers with =200k files, it sucks out all of my RAM.

I had hoped that making a `Foreach-obejct{}` after the `Get-AzStorageBlob` would make it run through the object right after so that it wouldnt store it.

```
#Account information
$StorageAcc = "StorageAccount-info"
$StorageAccKey = "StorageAccKey-info"
$containername = "container1"

#Create a storage context
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAcc -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccKey 

Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $context | ForEach-Object {$_.ICloudBlob.SetStandardBlobTier("Archive")}
```

I expect this to run through a container with x amount of files without the pc crashing because of memory issues, time is not an issues.

Right now i can run thorugh 132k in 90 mins, that takes about 400Mb of my memory/RAM.
Thank you!

**EDIT:**
**For anybody how could need something like this.**
It will go through all the blobs and check if its has already been archived, this saves alot of time. It will also save the ContinuationToken in a text file,so that if something happens you dont have to start over. **Remember to edit the path for the file**

```
$StorageAcc = "StorageAccount-info"
$StorageAccKey = "StorageAccKey-info"
$containername = "container1"
$token = $null
$total = 0
$start = 0

#Create a storage context
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAcc -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccKey 
do{

$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $context -MaxCount 10000 -ContinuationToken $token
$Total += $Blobs.Count
    foreach ($blob in $blobs)
    {
        If($blob.ICloudBlob.Properties.StandardBlobTier -eq "cool"){

        $blob.ICloudBlob.SetStandardBlobTier("Archive")
        }

    }

if($Blobs.Length -le 0) { Break;}
    $Token = $Blobs[$blobs.Count -1].ContinuationToken;
    Echo "Total $Total blobs in container $ContainerName"
    add-content C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Token.txt $Token.NextMarker
        if($start -eq 0)
        {
        $start += 1
        $token.NextMarker = "Token"
        }
}
 While ($Token -ne $Null)
 Echo "Total $Total blobs in container $ContainerName the end"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hinted at in the documentation. You process them in [batches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-2.2.0). With some minor modification to their code this should work. Set the max return to what you need it to be.

```
$MaxReturn = 10000
$ContainerName = "abc"
$Total = 0
$Token = $Null
do
{
    $Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -MaxCount $MaxReturn  -ContinuationToken $Token
    $Total += $Blobs.Count
    if($Blobs.Length -le 0) { Break;}

    foreach($blob in $blobs) {
        $blob.ICloudBlob.SetStandardBlobTier("Archive")
    }


    $Token = $Blobs[$blobs.Count -1].ContinuationToken;
}
While ($Token -ne $Null)
Echo "Total $Total blobs in container $ContainerName archived"
```